# document.cookie are undefined in IE8 and IE 9

Tags: javascript, cookies, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to get existing cookie as below.

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i;
    var x;
    var y;
    var ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code in Firefox it gives me the existing cookie `getCookie('test_cookie')`. But when I try to get the same cookie in IE it returns `undefined`.

I have checked the cache and `test_cookie` exists and expires in one year.

What could be the main cause for this?

Comment: Put `console.log(document.cookie);` to check if it is really there or not.

Comment: Yes I got cookie in log even.

Comment: Put `console.log` statements, line by line and corner the line where the expected result is not met. For example, you can print `x` and `y`